# Download complete web page from Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

is it possible to programmatically download complete web page (like Chrome can when you hit `Ctrl+S`) from **my web extension**?
I need the HTML with accompanying resources (images etc), so [`pageCapture`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture) (MHTML) is not an option i guess (also downloading each resource with ajax separately is not an option here).

Comment: "also downloading each resource with ajax separately is not an option here" why?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understood your problem, are you writing your own extension or looking for one?

If you're looking for one I'd recommend [Save All Resources](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-all-resources/abpdnfjocnmdomablahdcfnoggeeiedb) extension.

Please note: ensure you are aware of the data that is shared by this extension with the developer (privacy).
Save All Resources collects the following:
Website content
For example: text, images, sounds, videos or hyperlinks

Comment: I need a custom save process (have to do some other stuff automatically before saving).

Answer (score -2):

yes you can by using HTTrack software. 
HTTrack allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack arranges the original site's relative link-structure. Simply open a page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and you can browse the site from link to link, as if you were viewing it online. HTTrack can also update an existing mirrored site, and resume interrupted downloads. HTTrack is fully configurable, and has an integrated help system.

download here. 
https://www.httrack.com/page/2/en/index.html

so hope the answers.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in the original question. I need to do it from my web extension. I can already get what I need by saving full web page, now I need a way to do exactly that programmatically.